# How to get value of certain node in nodeList?

Tags: javascript, nodelist, selectors-api

So I'm using querySelectorAll on four inputs on the page (height, weight, age, gender), and adding a change event to each.

`var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');`

`input.addEventListener('change', changeValue));`

If I then wanted to create a string of all of the items values, during the loop, how would I do that?

```
function changeValue() {
  this.name === 'weight' ? this.value + 'lbs' + this.name === 'height' ? this.value + 'inches';
}
```

Basically, I'm not sure how I get a specific inputs value out of the loop without using something as generic as an index.

Answer (score 3):

Well you're kind of treating the ternary operator `? :` wrong.
Nevertheless, here's my way of implementation. The answers provided above would do but I like to keep a mapped object which won't need me to write a case expression it's cleaner too.

```
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  //var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input')) for older browsers not supporting forEach on Node lists


    function changeValue(){
      var mapped = {
         "weight":" lbs",// note the extra space is intentional
         "height":" inches" // note the extra space is intentional
      }
      this.value = this.value + mapped[this.name];

    }
    inputs.forEach(function(e){
        e.addEventListener('change', changeValue);
    })
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/aminajani17/abbxbLoo/

Answer (score 1):

"*If I then wanted to create a string of all of the items values*"

You could `JSON.stringify` them. Also, one approach that I use a lot when dealing with sets in Javascript is to iterate with `forEach` in arrays.

Something like this would do it without much complexity:

```
function getInputItems(inputs) {
    var inputItems = {};
    Array.from(inputs).forEach(function(item) {
        inputItems[item.name] = inputItems[item.value];
    });
    return JSON.stringify(inputItems);
}
```

**Edited:**

It seems that `querySelectorAll` implements `forEach` since ES5, so there is no need on a decent browser to convert `querySelectorAll` results with `Array.from`.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `nodeList` that implements `forEach`, but  `getElementsByTagName` doesn't, as it returns an `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: That's interesting, I was reading an article on css-tricks suggesting it doesn't work straight away: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/ . Maybe the support for `forEach` is something that been recently added?

Comment: This is part of the WHATWG DOM Living Standard (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). According to that page, there are implementations that don't conform to the standard. I've been using it in Chrome for over a year or so now.

Comment: Thanks for that! I was using Array.from systematically on dom results, but I guess I will challenge the need for it especially with Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `nodeList` that can be looped using the ECMAScript 5 `forEach` loop, but you will need something that can identify each element. An `id` is usually the best way:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var results = "";

inputs.forEach(function(input){
   input.addEventListener('change', changeValue));

   var postfix = "";

   // check the current input's id and determine the correct
   // unit of measurement/qualification for the element's value
   switch(input.id){
     case "height" :
       postfix = "inches";
       break;
     case "weight" :
       postfix = "lbs";       
       break;
     case "age" :
       postfix = "years";       
       break;
     case "gender" :
       postfix = "gender";       
       break; 
   }

   // Append the input's value and unit of measurement/qualification
   // to a string
   results += "," + input.value + postfix;
});

// output the final string
console.log(results);
```